# Read a file in a phonegap project folder after have downloaded it

Tags: javascript, cordova

I work on a phonegap project in which I have the following problem:

When I add a new file in any folder of the application (www/FOLDER), where the application is running, my file is unreachable via HTTP. Accessing it (on localhost:8000/uploads/FILE for example) returns a 404 error.

I have to recompile cordova and only then is the file accessible.

How can I get the application to recognize the file without recompiling?

PS: I use Cordova transfer plugin in order to download the file that I want to access later.
My code :

```
window.webkitRequestFileSystem(window.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fs){

        var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer(); 
        var uri = encodeURI("http://localhost:8080/findcare/api/users/offline?uploads=true"); //generate zip file
        var filename = uri.split("/").pop(); 
        var filePath = fs.root.fullPath() + 'uploads.zip'; //I'm not sure

        fileTransfer.download(
            uri,
            filePath,
            function(entry) {
                console.log("download complete: " + entry.toURL());
            },
            function(error) {
                console.log(error);
                console.log("download error source " + error.source);
                console.log("download error target " + error.target);
                console.log("upload error code " + error.code);
            },
            false,
            {
                withCredentials:true
            }  
        );


    }, function(e){console.log(e);});
```

Answer (score 0):

In phonegap, there are separate folders for each platform (`ios`, `android`, ...). Whenever you compile, phonegap copies all of the original files to the appropriate folders for each platform.

If you need to see the changed immidiately, I'd suggest you to use [Ionic](http://ionicframework.com/). It is build on top of phonegap and offers much more functionality. You can run `ionic serve` and it will start a web-server to serve your content in the browser. Whenever you change your files, it will restart the webserver automatically to show the latest version of your project.

Also, if you want to develop on your device and don't want to compile every time, for development phase you can use `ionic run --device --livereload`. It will install the app into the connected device and refreshes it whenever you change a file just like the browser.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Amir but that is not what i meant.
In fact, i use File transfert plugin to download a file with my app in a folder and after i want to read it.

Is it possible?